Flutter is stuck forever and never returns a response or error
I’m encountering an issue where Flutter becomes unresponsive, neither returning a response nor showing any errors.
Steps I’ve Tried: 
Deleted the /flutter/bin/cache directory, but the issue persists.
I have also tried reinstalling flutter.
Environment: 
OS: Debian 12
How can I resolve this?

